# "Building JavaScript bundle" muito demorado ao iniciar o Expo no Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

No React Native, seguindo a documentação oficial (passo a passo) consegui instalar as dependencias e tudo o que precisava para rodar meu primeiro projeto. Criei o diretório usando `expo init myApp`,  e logo em seguida iniciei com `expo start`, até aí tudo certo, no entanto, toda vez que ligo meu pc e vou conectar ao projeto pela primeira vez (usando o QR code) obtenho o seguinte no meu terminal:

```
Building JavaScript bundle [===============================            ] 73%
```

Isso demora cerca de 20 minutos pra ser completado e a tela do meu smartphone fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após os Building do JavaScript bundle serem completadas em 100% o meu app roda normalmente.

## Dúvidas:

1. É normal essa demora para iniciar o app pela primeira vez sempre que ligo o pc?
2. Se não, como contornar essa falha?

Comment: Questões de configuração de software, suporte e infraestrutura devem ser feitas em inglês no [su] ou [sf] conforme o assunto. Lembre-se de ler as regras específicas de cada comunidade antes de postar lá. Para futuras questões que estejam no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic) vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa lentidão pode acontecer sim. Lendo uma pergunta do SOen ([React Native Expo building very slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092692/react-native-expo-building-very-slowly)) e com base em experiências passadas, digo que pode ter a ver com a capacidade do seu computador ou com a conexão de Internet.

Como sugerido na pergunta do SOen, trago em tradução livre:

> Tente utilizar o Expo em um emulador no seu computador e verifique se
> está demorando tanto quanto no seu celular:
>
> - Se está mais rápido do que no seu celular, então verifique a conexão de Internet no celular em que você está testando
> - Se está tão lento quanto no seu celular, então tente remover o `node_modules` e reinstalar as dependências com `npm install` ou
>   `yarn`.

Adianto que já tive problemas com isso em uma máquina lenta, onde esse procedimento falhava muitas vezes quando eu tentava utilizar um `app.config.js` (veja [um issue sobre isso](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/2341)), mas mudando para uma máquina mais "potente", tudo funcionou normalmente.

---

Sobre a tela ficar branca enquanto está carregando, é exatamente o que isso significa: está carregando o bundle e então não tem nada para ser exibido ainda, por isso o app só funciona quando chega no 100%.